# src dataId value to dest newDataId its not copying

Tags: javascript

I tried to copy src dataId value to dest newDataId its not copying

below is the error message

Cannot convert undefined or null to object

any suggestion?

please refer below snippet

```
let src = {dataId: "test"}

let dest = {newDataId: null}

Object.assign(dest.newDataId, src.dataId)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.assign()` is used when you want to copy **all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object**.(more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) 
In your case you want to copy an object's property into another object and you can do it using `dest.newDataId = src.dataId`